# How to create generic Default Empty Cell for TableViewSource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In my application, I have a lot of List and every time I want to make sure that I always have a default cell for safety. That why, every time I create a list in my application, I recreate an empty Cell in my tableView.

I can't see any solution, except to use XIB for reusesability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a TableSourceBase that is going to manage your DefaultEmptyCell and any other cell that is commun to your app.
The trick here is to yield all your xib before using them. Otherwise you will have a crash.

```
public abstract class TableViewSourceBase : UITableViewSource
    {
        protected const string DefaultEmptyCellIdentifier = "DefaultEmptyCell";

        protected virtual IEnumerable<(UINib, string)> GetNibsForCellReuse()
        {
            yield return (UINib.FromName(DefaultEmptyCellIdentifier, null), DefaultEmptyCellIdentifier);
        }

        public void RegisterNibs(UITableView tableView)
        {
            foreach (var (xib, key) in GetNibsForCellReuse())
            {
                tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(xib, key);
            }
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = null;
            cell = (DefaultEmptyCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell(DefaultEmptyCellIdentifier);
            return cell;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Now that we have our Base Class

You can manage you empty cell in every TableSource.

```
public class ListTableViewSource : TableViewSourceBase
    {
        private const string SimpleCellIdentifier = "SimpleCell";

        public ListTableViewSource()
        {
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = null;

            if (indexPath.Row >= [COUNT])
                return base.GetCell(tableView, indexPath);

            //Load your other cells here according to your need

            return cell;
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<(UINib, string)> GetNibsForCellReuse()
        {
            yield return (UINib.FromName(SimpleCellIdentifier, null), SimpleCellIdentifier);

            foreach (var tuple in base.GetNibsForCellReuse())
            {
                yield return tuple;
            }
        }
    }
```

Like that you won’t have to bother to initiate your Xib, handle your identifier which is simpler like you ask.